# Error en bucle FOR iterador Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, bucle-for

**Buenas a todos, gracias por leer y responder!**

**Problema**:

> **Bucle FOR en lenguaje JAVASCRIPT toma valores ERRONEOS por razón que desconozco.**

**Objetivo**:

> **Recorrer un array (2 de longitud, porque estoy testeando) de usuarios proveniente del servidor (Django) mediante un Ajax jQuery, para utilizar la información (en este caso el nombre del usuario) en unos nuevos elementos (`<a>`) realizados con Javascript.**

Esta es la función donde ocurre el problema, la mayor información que obtuve fue que el problema esta en el "element.setAttribute()", porque al quitarlo, todo funciona perfecto...

```
function visualizarUsuarios(users){
const box = document.querySelector('#usuarios');
var a = document.createElement('a');  
a.classList.add("nombreUsuarios");
var username = ""
for(v = 0; v<users.length; v++){
    console.log(v,a)
    username=users[v].fields.username
    console.log(v,a,username)
    a.value = username
    console.log(v,a,username)
    a.setAttribute("href","http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/"+username+"/")
    console.log(v,a,username)
    box.appendChild(a);
    console.log(v,a,username)
}
```

---

Este es el RESULTADO en la consola, el cual muestra claramente que todos logs de `<a>`, mas precisamente su atributo `href` resulta con un valor totalmente raro...

[image: gg]

Omití mostrar el array para ahorrar tiempo, pero claramente se ve el valor "Jose" y el bucle agrega "Guido"
Agradezco cualquier ayuda, desconozco cual es el error :(

Answer (score 1):

Al no crear el elemento 'a' dentro del bucle siempre que modificas el atributo href lo haces para el elemento 'a' origen por lo que todos tus enlaces tendran siempre el valor del último elemento del array de users. Prueba a mover el document.createElement('a') dentro del bucle para crear un nuevo elemento 'a'
por cada user y así no alterar el atributo href.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio!